# How to submit only 1 input field in form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form where cmds are entered in cmdEntered Textarea and the same command is copied in logs Textarea.
I want only cmdEntered textarea to be sumbitted on form submit. Below is my code which I tried:

```
function inputKeyDown(evt, input) {
if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
    var textarea = document.getElementById("logs");
    textarea.value += "\n" + input.value;
    input.value = ""; 
    document.getElementById("form1").submit();
    return false;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

Enter Commands:< br>
<form action ="" method="post" id="form1">
<textarea rows="15" cols="80" id="cmdEntered" onkeydown="return     inputKeyDown(event, this);"></textarea>
<br><br></form>
Logs:<br>
<textarea rows="15" cols="80" id="logs" readonly></textarea>
```

Comment: If you dont need the second text area value ,dont use the $_POST[second field].

Comment: `disabled` form fields are also not submitted. You could add a submithandler and disable the unnecessary field before actually submitting.

Comment: could you provide an example

Comment: If the *logs* textarea is outside the form, it will not be submitted. You haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: when i press enter key.. all the text disappears. i dont want logs to go. i only want cmdEntered to get sumitted and logs to remain as it is.

Comment: assign "name" attribute only to that "<textarea>" which you want to submit

Comment: @Anishakrishnan your log textarea is not inside the form tag is won't get submitted  ...!

Comment: but after entering text in cmdEntered and pressing enter key... the whole page is getting refresh.

Comment: @Anisha yeah coz cmdEntered tag is inside the form tag so the action attribute in the form tag will make page to refresh...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Possibilities of passing value between client and server

1. ajax
2. xmlHTTPrequest
3. form tag in HTML

**Option 1:** Use ajax like this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4mb2U/2/)

```
$("#cmdEntered").keydown(function(event){
   // event.preventDefault();   
    if (event.keyCode == 13){
        $.ajax({
        url:'',
        data:{cmdEntered:$(this).val()},
            type:'POST',
            success:function(data){
              alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
    });
```

**Option 2:**  Avoid using $_POST['logs'] in your server side language(php)

Comment: is it possible that after the form submits, the content on the page does not get refreshed and the same form is displayed again.

Comment: updated the code and remove action,method attribute in form tag then it won't be refreshed

Comment: @AnishaKrishnan Here, I used click event you can use someother event like keydown, blur, keypress instead of click...

Comment: i was hoping to get a solution using javascript coz i dont know ajax

Comment: @Anisha Are you using jQuery or not in your project?

Comment: @Anisha Ok good In your case , if you use jquery ajax it will be easy coz jquery just simplify the task.. anyway check the demo if it is helpfull

Comment: how do i send the cmdEntered text to a java class where furthere validation is done

Comment: What do you mean by java class here?.. May i know what serverside language r u using?

Comment: @Anisha thanks for accepting my answer. hope it's helpfull for you